# Where can CSS be located if not in a CSS file?

Tags: css

I am attempting to locate some CSS rules but they do not exist in the index.php header tag, nor in the only CSS file which the header references.

Where else could they be?

Comment: Can you give us a URL for the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS can be located directly in your HTML files within the `<head>` tag wrapped in `<style>` tags. You can also style elements inline such as `<div style="width:100px;"></div>`

CSS files can import other CSS files via `@import`. It is also possible that styles are changed or added with Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, there is no CSS within the head tag.  There is an external stylesheet, which is referenced in the head tag.  But it does not contain a boatload of CSS which the site employs, but I cannot find.

Comment: Have you checked for CSS in inline style elements?

Comment: CSS files can also be imported using the @import function within .css files. It's also possibly that inline styles are set using javascript but the majority of the styles would not have this

Comment: No inline styles and no @import

Comment: some inline for minor JS but otherwise I just can't find a lot of CSS.  I must be missing something obvious

Comment: I have located it.  It was in a PHP file.  I am very new to all this, thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: @ChrisHayward If you use a decent browser you can simply inspect the DOM and find out where all (computed) styles are coming from.

Comment: @PeeHaa Hey thanks, I use Safari's Developer tools however as far as I can tell it doesn't show me where the computed styles are coming from.  I can edit them for preview in the browser, but it does not show where they actually exist (in what file).  If they do I don't know where that feature is in the dev tools.  Do you?

Comment: @ChrisHayward The file in which the styles can be found are [under styles](http://imgur.com/i9DbH) or if they are inline styles they are under `element.style()`.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Rules can also be assigned through JavaScript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/)/jQuery.

Comment: We pointed that out in the comments to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can [import a stylesheet directly through .htaccess](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.6), but the is only supported by Firefox and Opera at the moment.